# CSS media query doesn't work after using react build

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm developing a react app using Create-React-App. I have a CSS file that contains following code:

```
.gallery {
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 33%;
}


@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .gallery {
    column-count: 1;
    column-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

When I'm running `npm start`, files loaded as follow:

[image: Screen during development]

But when I build the app using command `npm run build`, files are not loaded intently. Each photos loaded separately.

[image: Screen after build]

As I explored, I found some answers suggest to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

inside `<head></head>`, I also included that. Here's what my `<head></head>` tag contains:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <title>Photo Poll</title>
    <link href="/static/css/2.27df2d27.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/main.aae8b75c.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">       
</head>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: paste the content inside `head` tag of `public/index.html` file. Maybe that will be helpful to understand this issue.

Comment: I added the content.

Comment: cool. Head content looks fine to me. Any console errors in dev tools?

Comment: No. Nothing shows in console.

Comment: Also, have you or someone in your team modified the build? (like extending webpack config or modifying babel plugins etc)

Comment: I use the built-in configuration, nothing is modified manually. Thanks for your kind inquiry.

Comment: Not sure.. try removing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` and build it? (that is the only thing looks suspicious as per your post to me)

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Nothing happens. But I noticed a thing, if `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` included, it works on Chrome.

Comment: Try mentioning these meta tags on top of head, just after `title` tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: Try checking my answer. (_if that doesn't work, I will delete it - but that is how the sequence of tags should be_)

Comment: I am not sure what could be the issue. As I see, it can be issue in head tag contents, or webpack/babel transpiling, or maybe as simple as browser is zoomed in. if this is other than that, then I can't think of anything else. Good luck.

Comment: @Mr_Green could you please check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue.

I changed the CSS code as follow:

```
.gallery {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-width: 33%;
  -moz-column-width: 33%;
  column-width: 33%;
}


@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .gallery {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-width: 100%;
    -moz-column-width: 100%;
  column-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

But still nothing happened. Then I find that inside `build/static/css` there is a file named `main.d31b7c3b.chunk.css`, which contains `gallery` class as follow:

```
.gallery{-webkit-column-count:3;-webkit-column-width:33%;columns:33% 3}@media (max-width:450px){.gallery{-webkit-column-count:1;-webkit-column-width:100%;columns:100% 1}}
```

So, what happened is, somehow `npm run build` excluded other CSS properties that I put in my original code. So I changed it manually as follow:

```
.gallery{-webkit-column-count: 3;-moz-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;-webkit-column-width: 33%;-moz-column-width: 33%;column-width: 33%;}@media (max-width:450px){.gallery{-webkit-column-count: 3;-moz-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;-webkit-column-width: 33%;-moz-column-width: 33%;column-width: 33%;}}
```

And now everything is set!

Comment: hmm still that is not the root cause. but anyway, happy that you are able to move forward.